# Building a craps table program in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In craps if your first roll is 7 or 11 then you win. If it's 2 or 3 or 12 then you lose. If it's any other number, then you have to roll again until you either hit that number or crap out by hitting 7 or 11.

What I am stuck on is basically that I have hit a number but I need the program to save the number that was randomly selected and start over. And if it starts over and hits a different number without crapping out to start over again until the number is hit or it craps out.

Some explanation on theory and basic fundamental programming would really help me out. I'm not entirely sure where to go from where I have already started.

Python:

```py
import random
roll = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)
numbers = roll == 1 or roll == 4 or roll == 5 or roll == 6 or roll == 8 or roll == 9 or roll == 10
while True:
    if roll == 7 or roll == 11:
        print('nice')
        break
    elif  roll == 3 or roll == 2 or roll == 12:
        print('crapped out')
        break
    elif numbers:
        print('your number is:', roll, "roll again...")
        break
```

I just want the program to be like "OK this is the number rolled. I'm going to remember that and start again to see if it can hit the same number."

Comment: this:  `numbers = roll == 1 or roll == 4 or roll == 5 or roll == 6 or roll == 8 or roll == 9 or roll == 10` is evaluated once and gets to be True or False - it is never changed after that. Using `numbers = roll in (1,4,5,6,8,9,10)` does exactly the same. You need to _reevaluated_ numbers for each newly trown dices. You never _roll_ dices again, so the value will never change and you either win, loose or sit in an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to be missing is actually *rolling* the dice within your loop.

The general idea is to roll the dice once and check for an instant win or loss.

If it's *not* an instant win/loss, *then* you enter a loop, continuously re-rolling the dice until such time as you have a win or loss.

The following pseudocode<sup>(a)</sup> (with comments) shows how to do this:

```
# Store first throw.

firstThrow = rnd(1..6) + rnd(1..6)
print "First throw " firstThrow

# Set winner if house or player wins on first throw.

winner = ''
if firstThrow is one of (7, 11):            winner = 'player'
else if firstThrow is one of (2, 3, 12):    winner = 'house'

# Loop until a winner found (may have already happened above).

while winner == '':
    # Get subsequent throw.

    throw = rnd(1..6) + rnd(1..6)
    print "Next throw " throw

    # Set winner (exits loop) if win or lose.

    if throw is one of (7, 11):             winner = 'house'
    else if throw is same as firstThrow:    winner = 'player'

# Have a winner, output it.

print "Winner was " winner
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> For questions that are almost certainly classwork, I find it better to provide pseudo-code and let the asker convert that into their language of choice, since that tends to make better developers.

The conversion to Python is relatively simple in this case but I urge you to try it yourself. If you're struggling with that, I include some Python code below (in the hope you won't use it verbatim, a bad idea anyway since any educator you (or others) may have, will *also* be able to see this answer and grade accordingly):

```
import random

# Store first throw.

firstThrow = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)
print("First throw", firstThrow)

# Set winner if house or player wins on first throw.

if firstThrow in (7, 11):      winner = 'player'
elif firstThrow in (2, 3, 12): winner = 'house'
else:                          winner = ''

# Loop until a winner found (may have already happened above).

while winner == '':
    # Get subsequent throw.

    throw = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)
    print("Next throw", throw)

    # Set winner (exits loop) if win or lose condition found.

    if throw in (7, 11):       winner = 'house'
    elif throw == firstThrow:  winner = 'player'

# Have a winner, output it.

print("Winner was",  winner)
```

And here are some sample runs for confirmation:

```
First throw 11
Winner was player

First throw 7
Winner was player

First throw 4
Next throw 7
Winner was house

First throw 9
Next throw 10
Next throw 7
Winner was house

First throw 11
Winner was player
First throw 10
Next throw 5
Next throw 11
Winner was house

First throw 8
Next throw 5
Next throw 11
Winner was house

First throw 8
Next throw 7
Winner was house
```

Comment: You say its not python ... but  `if firstThrow is 7 or 11` is one of the most occuring errors for python beginners - I really do not like to see this here - using `firstThrow in (7,11)` would be better.

Comment: @Patrick, it's not my intent to write the code for OP, rather to show the logic. I've made it clear that this is pseudo-code. I've also modified the pseudo-code so it's much harder to drop it into Python as is.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
numbers_occurred_till_now =[] # here we are going to store all the dice value that will occur.
while True:
    roll = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)
    numbers_occurred_till_now.append(roll) # when the number is generated, we are appending it in the list.
    if roll == 7 or roll == 11:
        print('nice')
        print(numbers_occurred_till_now)
        break
    elif  roll == 3 or roll == 2 or roll == 12:
        print('crapped out')
        print(numbers_occurred_till_now)
        break
    elif numbers:
        print('your number is:', roll, "roll again...")
        print(numbers_occurred_till_now)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem (and what was the OP probles to begin with) would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.